# IE Setting in group policy --- Disable automatically detect setting in LAN Settings

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

have been trying to hunt this down for weeks with no luck.

i need a way to disable a setting..

in IE.

Tools > Connections > Lan Setting
i need to uncheck "automatically detect settings"

does anyone know a way i can do this via group policy.

all user on IE 9 or IE 10

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Greg,

There isn't a specific GPO setting for this.

You can import IE settings from a local machine into a GPP if you want and apply them that way.  For instance, you can load up a vanilla IE, uncheck the box, and then import those settings into a GPO for deployment.  But usually this causes more issues than it is worth in the long run.

The best alternative it would seem is to manipulate the registry, again via a GPP.

From the link:

> ```
> Here's the key you are after:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
> ```
>
> Settings\Connections\DefaultConnectionSettings
>
> ```
> Look for byte number 8 (starts at 0 so count 9).
>
> Here's the values it can have:
>
> Byte number 8 can take different values as per your settings.
> The value is :
> 09 when only 'Automatically detect settings' is enabled
> 03 when only 'Use a proxy server for your LAN' is enabled
> 0B when both are enabled
> 05 when only 'Use automatic configuration script' is enabled
> 0D when 'Automatically detect settings' and 'Use automatic configuration script' are enabled
> 07 when 'Use a proxy server for your LAN' and 'Use automatic configuration script' are enabled
> 0F when all the three are enabled.
> 01 when none of them are enabled.
> The next three bytes are zeros (Bytes 9 to B)
>
>
>
> You probably want to set this from 09 (enabled) to 01 (disabled).
>
>
>
> More info on here: http://www.visualbasicscript.com/tm.aspx?high=&m=30518&mpage=1#46540
>
> You will also find a post slightly further down (number 15) containing a VB script that the author says will change only that byte. I have not tested it.
> ```

Full info can be found here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/cb6abb30-4360-4d3d-93fc-61823b2a5c20/turn-off-auto-detect-settings-in-ie-using-gpo?forum=winserverGP

Answer (score 2):

A bit modified version of the script provided by @Knuckle-Dragger and ready to be put in a .cmd/.bat file to just click and run the script.

```
@echo off

powershell -Command "& {"^
 "$settings = (Get-ItemProperty "^
 "-Path     'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections' "^
 "-Name DefaultConnectionSettings).DefaultConnectionSettings;"^
 "$settings[8] = $settings[8] -band (-bnot 8);"^
 "Set-ItemProperty -Path     'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections' -Name DefaultConnectionSettings -Value $settings"^
"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the other answer, here is a powershell script to flip the bit.

```
$flip = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections' -Name DefaultConnectionSettings).DefaultConnectionSettings
$flip[8]
$flip[8] = !$flip[8]
$flip[8]
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections' -Name DefaultConnectionSettings -Value $flip
```

Answer (score 1):

On a typical workstation I manually unchecked the "Automatically Detect Settings" option, then copied-imported this registry setting into the User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Registry:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Connections\DefaultConnectionSettings

```
Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER 
Key path: Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections 
Value name: DefaultConnectionSettings 
Value type: REG_BINARY 
Value data: 4600000015000000010000000000000000000000000000000100000020000000687474703A2F2F777061642E73746166662E6C6F63616C2F777061642E64617452E5D052E2BACE010000000000000000000000000100000002000000CDBDC36F000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Not sure you care about the Value data above—I just imported the whole thing...

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be undocumented setting that works fine on Windows 2012/2012R2 so it's possible it may work on Windows 7 and up.

> Registry Key : HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\ DWORD AutoDetect = 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

save it as vbs and apply at GPO logon script or if doesn't helps see here
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/askie/2014/12/17/how-to-use-gpp-registry-to-uncheck-automatically-detect-settings/

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoDetect","0","REG_DWORD"
```